# PyQt5.uic no reference found in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I have wanted to upload my UI file and import uic and uiloader from PyQt5. However, when importing `from PyQt5.uic import loadUI` it gives me an error for both, saying unresolved reference, even though both files are in the same folder as PyQt5 itself, which works.

I've added a picture below to show that the uic folder is there with everything needed inside.

[image: UIC Folder]

[image: PyCharm error]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. The PyQt5 installed by PyCharm does not know of any uic module. There may be a solution, see:
https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5ac/

Or alternatively (puh) install Anaconda and use spyder.